# How to print 3 different values per line in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream

My program reads 366 lines of data from a file, each line has 2 values; minimum temperature and maximum temperature. I want to output when there were three consecutive days where the temperature went above a certain number n, that the user enters.
This is what I have:

```
cout<<"Please enter a number to search: ";
cin>>n;
out<<endl;
out<<"Occasions during the year when there were three consecutive days 
where the temperature went above "<<n<<" are:"<<endl;
out<<"Days: ";
for(int x=0; x<366; x=x+1){
            in>>minimum[x];
            in>>maximum[x];


             if(minimum[x]>n){
              day1=x;
            }

             if(maximum[x]>n){
                day1=x;
            }
            out<<"Days: "<<day1<<", "<<day2<<", "<<day3<<endl;
            }

}
```

I'm having trouble understanding how to update day 2 and day 3 to a different element of the array that satisfies the condition. When the condition is met, I want to store the days and print them like:

Occasions during the year (if any) when there were three consecutive days where the temperature went above 34 are:

Days:103, 104, 105

Days:107, 108, 109

Days:288, 289, 290

the days are the locations in the array.

Comment: What happens if there are 4 consecutive days?  Are days 1,2, and 3, separate from 2,3, and 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something more like this:

```
cout << "Please enter a number to search: ";
cin >> n;

out << endl;
out << "Occasions during the year when there were three consecutive days where the temperature went above " << n << " are:" << endl;

int firstday, numdays = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < 366; ++x)
{
    in >> minimum[x];
    in >> maximum[x];

    if (maximum[x] > n)
    {
        ++numdays;

        if (numdays == 1)
            firstday = x;
        else if (numdays == 3)
        {
            out << "Days: " << firstday << ", " << firstday+1 << ", " << firstday+2 << endl;
            numdays = 0;
        }
    }
    else
        numdays = 0;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
cout << "Please enter a number to search: ";
cin >> n;

out << endl;
out << "Occasions during the year when there were three consecutive days where the temperature went above " << n << " are:" << endl;

for (int x = 0; x < 366; ++x)
{
    in >> minimum[x];
    in >> maximum[x];
}

for (int x = 0; x < 366-2; ++x)
{
    if (maximum[x] > n)
    {
        int firstday = x;
        int numdays = 1;

        for (int y = 1; y < 3; ++y)
        {
            if (maximum[x+y] > n)
                ++numdays;
            else
                break;
        } 

        if (numdays == 3)
            out << "Days: " << firstday << ", " << firstday+1 << ", " << firstday+2 << endl;

        x += (numdays-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. I'm only used to breaks in java but I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you break this down into smaller parts. For example, you could do this in two broad steps:

1. Read in all the data
2. Find all sets of 3 days which are above the given temperature

By doing each of these separately, you can focus on one piece at a time, rather than trying to do both.

Note, that you only need `if(maximum[x] > n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an int variable to act as a flag. Every time you get a 'good' day, add 1 to that flag and subtract 1 if not. So, in the end, just add an if statement that checks if that flag variable is three, and then print the value.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Don't "subtract 1" on a 'bad' day.  Reset back to 0 instead. Otherwise, lets say `n` is 100, then a sequence like `101 101 98 102 101` would get incorrectly treated as 3 consecutive days.

Comment: Yeah! Missed that.